# Enable or disable pan, rotation and zoom on key pressed event

Tags: c++, vtk

I'm trying to set up a vtkInteractorStyle Class 
(vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera) handling events to disable pan, zoom, or 
rotation. Each of these functions would be enabled or disabled according to an user's pressed key. 
I think the most common way of doing it, is to generate an event handler 
function for each different key and, inside it's block setting some flag of 
the class vtkRenderWindowInteractor to false or true using a function like 
setPan(false) or setPan(true), etc.

But as you may know there's no such function or method on the vtkRenderWindowInteractor class.

### Is my approach correct? Does someone have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There indeed is no such flag to turn it off and I see no other way to to so without modifying the vtk's code (see  [vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Interaction/Style/vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.cxx) / [vtkInteractorStyle.cxx](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Rendering/Core/vtkInteractorStyle.cxx)). The way I would go about it would be to make a new class inheriting from vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera, added the three boolean flags to it (+ setters) and override the StartRotate, StartZoom and StartPan methods such as:

```
void vtkMyNewStyle::StartZoom()
{
    if (zoomIsEnabled) // your flag set by setZoom(bool)
        Superclass::StartZoom();
}
```